# Chaining implicit conversion operators

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion

I've got a class which I need to implicitly convert to a few things, with intermediate values, e.g.

```
struct outer {
    struct inner {
        operator T() { return T(); }
    };
    operator inner() { return inner(); }
};
```

If I have this structure, is it *always* valid to do, e.g.

```
void f(T t);
outer o;
f(o);
```

Comment: What is `T`?  A template Type?

Comment: @MooingDuck: A type. It doesn't matter what T is. It's not a template because I didn't take any parameters?

Comment: `f(o)` would require two user defined conversions, while the standard allows maximum std-conversion -> u-d conversion -> std-conversion.

Comment: The complier will only perform one implicit conversion automatically. Normally implicit conversions are best avoided - they tend to make code harder to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 11):

`§13.3.3.1.2 [over.ics.user] p1`

> A user-defined conversion sequence consists of an initial standard conversion sequence followed by **a user-defined conversion** (12.3) followed by a second standard conversion sequence.

Notice the singular and the missing of the word "sequence". Only one user-defined conversion will ever be considered during an implicit conversion sequence.

Comment: Is there a corresponding bit that states only one "user-defined conversion sequence" will occur?

Comment: @peachykeen that's the very definition of parameter passing. For class types it involves one user defined conversion sequence (if the argument type differs from the parameter type) followed by a final copy of the temporary resulting `T` into the parameter of type `T`.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
struct Foo {}; // renamed T in Foo to avoid confusion!

struct outer {
        struct inner {
                operator Foo() { return Foo(); }
        };

        operator inner() { return inner(); }

        template <typename T>
        operator T () {
                return operator inner();
        }
};

int main() {
        void f(Foo t);
        outer o;
        f(o);
}
```

But only because `f` is not overloaded, so it is not really a solution.

Comment: If that was acceptable, I'd just make the `Foo` operator in the outer class.

Comment: I am not surprised that this is not "acceptable", but it is the best "fix" I got.