# Function matching in vector constructors

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class HasPtrValue {
public:
    HasPtrValue(const HasPtrValue& h): ps(new std::string(*h.ps)) { std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;}
    HasPtrValue(const std::string &s = std::string()): ps(new std::string(s)) { std::cout << "string/default" << std::endl;}
    ~HasPtrValue() { delete ps; }
private:
    std::string *ps;
};

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s = "stackoverflow";
    vector<HasPtrValue> a(5, s);
}
```

The above code compiles fine outputting:

```
string/default
copy
copy
copy
copy
copy
```

This suggests to me the vector first directly initialises a temporary HasPtrValue object using the string object (doing HasPtrValue(s))and then copy-constructs the 5 elements from this temporary. How come, then, the following code does not compile:

```
int main(){
    vector<HasPtrValue> a(5, "stackoverflow");
}
```

If it was directly initialising the HasPtrValue (doing HasPtrValue("stackoverflow")) then there would be no issue in the const string& constructor taking up the role of creating the temporary. I get the error;

```
 error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<HasPtrValue>::vector(int, const char [14])'|
```

I thought I'd try it with a simpler class that uses an int constructor and converts from a double:

```
class A{
public:
    A(const int& a): x(a) { }
    int x = 2;
};

int main(){
    vector<A> a(5, 5.5);

}
```

Except this compiles fine. What part of the vector implementation prevents using a const char* conversion in the constructor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chaining implicit conversion operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610511/chaining-implicit-conversion-operators)

Comment: Answer is already given. Just add this:
`HasPtrValue(const char* s) : ps(new std::string(s)) { std::cout << "string/constcharptr" << std::endl; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it needs two user defined conversions, `const char*` -> `std::string`, and then `std::string` -> `HasPtrValue`, but only once user defined implicit conversion is permitted in an implicit conversion sequence.

13.3.3.1.2$1 User-defined conversion sequences [over.ics.user]

> A user-defined conversion sequence consists of an initial standard
>   conversion sequence followed by a userdefined conversion (12.3)
>   followed by a second standard conversion sequence.

Note here only one level of user defined implicit conversion is legal. For your case this must be handled by explicit conversions; So you can:

```
vector<HasPtrValue> a(5, std::string("stackoverflow"));
```

Comment: Or since c++14 `"stackoverflow"s`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
    vector<HasPtrValue> a(5, string("stackoverflow"));
}
```

Your constructor requires `std::string` and "stackoverflow" is `char` array.
Alternatively you can define additional constructor accepting `char[]`.